# Disable context menu (right click) when using Facebook Unity SDK

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

i'm currently developing a game on facebook using Unity3D and i'd realy love to use the Facebook SDK. The problem is that the game NEED to use the right mouse button to perform some core actions (jetpack).

Since facebook loads a ".unity3d" file over a html frame, i've lost all the control over the javascript that loads the Unity3d, thus, everytime someone tries to use jetpack, the builtin context menu appears. :/

It's really easy to disable it via javascript, it would be great if threr was a checkbox on the Facebook app settings like: "Disable Context Menu?  -Check!"

Thanks already!

Comment: The context menu is disabled in Facebook canvas by default. Where are you seeing this?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook disables the context menu in the HTML they create in the IFRAME that holds the Unity webplayer.  You may be able to change the attribute of the embed tag they make with a Application.ExternalEval

The embed is in a div with id=unityPlayerEmbed and the attribute is disablecontextmenu.

David